# get size and positions of icons and bottom strip / home button in live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to get the sizes and positions of everything (or at least anything) that "obstructs" the view to live wallpaper?

I would like to make a wallpaper that would make special effects around icons or at least bottom strip.

Also, is the size of the bottom strip (the one with home button) in any way standard so I could guess its size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

At least, not unless whatever launcher the user is using offers a special API to do so. But even so you cannot guarantee that the user will be using that launcher as this is Android and that component can be replaced by a third-party launcher (e.g., LauncherPro, Go Launcher EX, etc.)

The only real way to do this would be to give the user the option in the settings of your live wallpaper to change where it does and does not display things.

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of determining that wallpaper is obscured (not what it is obscured by), but I was afraid it is not possible... Thanks for the answer, I'll wait if someone comes with a way, otherwise I'll accept it.